# All the router's interfaces status is down

Tags: openstack, router

I created a router, and in it I created a interface for the router:

[image]

But you see, the status all is Down, how to debug the interface? why all are down?

---

**EDIT-1**

In the `/var/log/neutron/server.log`, I use `cat server.log | grep router`, get the below information:

[image]

```
2017-08-04 08:56:13.835 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 08:56:50.830 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 08:57:27.826 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 08:58:04.822 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 08:58:41.817 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 08:59:18.813 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 08:59:55.809 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:00:32.805 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:01:09.800 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:01:46.796 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:02:23.792 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:03:00.788 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:03:37.783 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:04:14.779 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:04:51.775 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:05:28.771 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:06:05.766 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:06:42.762 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:07:19.757 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:07:56.753 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:08:33.750 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:09:10.746 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:09:47.743 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:10:24.739 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:11:01.735 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:11:38.731 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:12:15.728 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:12:52.724 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:13:29.721 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:14:06.718 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
2017-08-04 09:14:43.715 103451 ERROR neutron.db.agentschedulers_db [req-7a2dde4e-5aca-499d-8946-5bfd965cea93 - - - - -] Exception encountered during router rescheduling.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find in my `/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini` configuration file, I did not configured the `ml2 type_drivers` and `mechanism_drivers`. So I config them:

```
# openstack-config --set /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini ml2 type_drivers flat,vlan,vxlan
# openstack-config --set /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini ml2 mechanism_drivers linuxbridge,l2population
```

And restart the neutron-server:

```
systemctl restart neutron-server.service
systemctl restart  neutron-l3-agent.service
```

Now, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Because your ports' management status are all up, so there are some likely reason as below.

1. The peer is down.
2. There is no cable on your interface.

Comment: This is openstack, do you mean a hypostatic router?